# Why does it seem like the JavaScript community is somewhat friendlier than the Python community on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Now, I don't mean to verbally bash members of the Python community, but it's just a trend I see.

I'm familiar with JavaScript and Python (and a tiny bit of Java). I answer questions in both tags, but the ones in JavaScript are generally received nicely, and hardly ever get downvoted even though the answers aren't really the best.

However, almost every answer I post in Python gets downvoted (there was a good reason for a few, granted) more heavily than in JavaScript, HTML or CSS. Is there a psychological reason or is it just my JavaScript competence being superior to my Python competence?

I did once post an answer to a Python question that showcased an efficacious solution involving "unpacking" (apologies for unfamiliar members of the community) which got downvoted immediately after an upvote. This didn't seem to occur in the JavaScript community where I got **no** downvotes at all.

Comment: "the ones in JavaScript are generally received nicely, and hardly ever get downvoted even though the answers aren't really the best" I can only get to so many... :P

Comment: downvotes aren't "unfriendly"

Comment: Just a quick look at your last Python answer... 1) as is, it's going to raise an exception and 2) it also contains a subtle gotcha left over from the OPs code which means even if you fix the exception - the output is still going to be incorrect... It doesn't look like you checked your code before posting... (the tooltip for down-voting says "This answer is not useful"... which code that won't run and when fixed will product incorrect results pretty much is...). Could be the Python community are more thorough in checking these things...

Comment: _"This didn't seem to occur in the JS community where I got no downvotes at all."_ This is unfortunate. I will see to the JS community to understand the reason why their posts are lacking downvotes.

Comment: "However almost every answer I post in Python gets downvoted (there was a good reason for a few, granted)" - So those downvotes to your answers were indeed justified.  So have you fix your answers, so the users who downvoted your answers, can reverse their vote?  **Voting is never "unfriendly".**

Comment: Remember that it costs people to downvote answers. They aren't just doing it for smurfs and giggles.

Comment: It could still be that you are just worse in Python than in JavaScript. Please do statistics in order to motivate that there might be a real effect.

Comment: Problem: I've been programming py longer than js. The questions I target arw mostly to do with lists or dicts or string manipulation.

Comment: @expressjs123 - In that case, you should be able to easily write high quality answers to Python questions, and be able to easily incorporate any feedback you do receive into your answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Cordiality is not measured in downvotes.  But, I would actually consider your perspective to be inverted; those who care enough to give you correction should be regarded higher than those who would see you make a mistake and leave it alone.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's just that the py community pay more attention

Comment: @expressjs123 also with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64645659) - you've had a comment that it doesn't work but haven't edited it to fix it? (Or done anything else...)

Comment: Maybe he or she doesn't need so much correction in one of the tags. We simply don't know what is going on here.

Comment: Sorry @CodyGray, normally I'm okay with your edits, but this time I feel like I've said what I said the way I wanted to say it and with all of the detail I needed to include.

Comment: Well, I tried. :-p